# перенос скрипта с локального сервера на боевой

Tags: linux, apache, perl

Есть скрипт, написанный на перле, который авторизируется на сайте. Изначально тестился на локальной версии сервера(поднимал на 8 винде, xampp). Скрипт отлично работает, как на локальном, так и на боевом серверах, но если я его запускаю через перл установленный на винде. Основной сервер(на дебиане, apache2) выдает 404 ошибку, когда пытаюсь запустить с его перла.

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: А по сути вопроса ничего не ясно. может 404 ошибка потому что скрипт коннектится на другой сервер и там просто нет нужной страницы. А может сам скрипт при формировании URL при обращении использует какую то информацию из ОС которая на linux отсутствует или другая. Для начала рекомендую вывести на экран точный URL по которому идет обращение и от этого плясать

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну тут не столько вкусы, сколько принятая терминология. основной сервер и локальный сервер. локальный и удаленный сервер. дев сервер и боевой сервер. и т.д. в индустрии чаще используется "боевой" или "продакшен" для серверов, которые доступны клиентам, а "основной" сервер - может быть чем угодно, может он контент раздает, или управляет кластером. Ну, я не столько спорил, сколько вносил ясность

Comment: Вопрос для цыганок-гадалок :)

Comment: @NicholasGoncharov к сайту на вашем же сервере пытаетесь подключиться или нет? К какому адресу происходит подключение? Не _должно_ происходить по вашему мнению, а _фактически_ происходит - сделайте перед подключением вывод значения той переменной, в которой хранится адрес.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте в свой скрипт логирование; проверьте, какие адреса и пути используются в скрипте. Действительно ли по этим адресам находится то, что должно быть?

Может, какая-то проблема с правами, пользователем или группой на Debian сервере.

Из вашего вопроса не очень понятно, какие меры были предприняты для решения проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

> Добавьте в свой скрипт логирование

Зачем? TS пишет, что ему выдаётся 404 ошибка. Значит она уже должна быть в логах! Надо просто найти её в апачевском логе и посмотреть, куда там идёт РЕАЛЬНОЕ обращение. Очевидно, что проблема вызвана разной структурой дерева каталогов на серверах на винде и дебиане. В принципе, может быть даже одинаковая файловая деревяшка, но разные права доступа. Или по разному настроены конфигурации виртуальных серверов там и там. В любом случае - надо смотреть лог и проверь путь, который в этом логе прописан.

Comment: откуда инфа что сайт находится на том же сервере? У вас шар хрустальный в кладовке лежит? А если подключение к стороннему серверу? Как вы будете его апачевский лог смотреть? ) Совет добавить в скрипт логирование архиправильный и это вообще первейшее что надо сделать при неправильной работе скрипта - убедиться что он работает с правильными данными.

Comment: **откуда инфа что сайт находится на том же сервере?** т.е. у нас уже три сервера ?

Comment: **Как вы будете его апачевский лог смотреть? )** Если я делаю сайт на сервере в Занзибаре, то у меня есть доступ к его логу. Потому, что я за это плачу занзибарские тугрики! А если мне не дают доступа к логам на моём виртуальном сервере в Занзибаре, то надо просто искать другого провайдера.

Comment: А вы всегда, когда видите вопрос, выдумываете какие-то свои ситуации, не описанные автором? Я ща открою страшную тайну, но скриптом (даже на perl'е!) можно подключиться (по крайней мере попытаться) к любому сайту, даже который не вами сделан и не на вашем сервере находится. Например к ru.stackoverflow.com. И да, он после этого может вернуть код ответа 404. Такие дела.

Comment: **Я ща открою страшную тайну**  я думаю, что не обязательно  разговаривать в таком тоне :-)  Я предполагаю, что если 404 код возвратил удалённый сервер, на котором Я ничего не крутил(!!!), то значит - он сказал правду, виноват действительно я и мне его логи не нужны.  А если ошибка на локальном компе (пусть он и называется сервером), то достаточно просто посмотреть УРЛ в его сообщении 404. Какой Вам ещё лог нужен?

Comment: Всё просто - нужно журналирование операций, которые выполняет скрипт. Откуда он получил значение переменных, чем они равны, какие операции над ними проводятся. Вывести это в отдельный файл или на консоль и скорее всего это и позволит установить на каком этапе действительные значения перестают совпадать с ожидаемыми.

Comment: **Всё просто** - но вот я никак не могу понять... :-( Если TS увидел (!!!) код 404, то в этом же сообщении должен быть ошибочный URL. Или что-то не так ?

Comment: нет, почему? Сервер вернёт код ошибки, но он не станет возвращать при этом URL по которому была получена эта ошибка. Он просто скажет - "404 Not found." Он не будет возвращать так же и ошибочный URL.